# disabling x to install graphics nvidia graphics card drivers

Tags: drivers

I'm trying to install my nvidia geforce 555m graphics card drivers but when i run the .run file it tells me to disable all x server windows. I googled a bit but didn't find answers. I'm running unity by the way thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to use nvidias own installer because what happens then is outside of ubuntu's package management.
Just install using a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

and reboot.

In case you need the absolute latest drivers use the x-swat-PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

and reboot.